# Microsoft Azure Copy Image across Regions

Tags: azure

I have used the "az image copy" to copy images across regions. But this doesn't create a copy with the Data disks which was with the source image. Any other extensions parameters to help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're right, as the extension shows the data disks are ignored by this extension. According to this, it seems the extension is designed to ignore the data disks in the image copy and there are no parameters to achieve what you want.

But it's just an extension, maybe it will be improved when it was integrated into the release version of Azure CLI.

The solution for you in the current situation is that you can export the data disk and import it to the region you want. Then you can attach the data disk to your VM manually.